# get rank of weekly leaderboard in GameKit of iOS

Tags: ios, gamekit, leaderboard

I want to give a feedback to a player who's on the top of the leaderboard.

i do it for daily leaderboard like this:

```
GKScore* gkScore = [self createScoreForeCategory:kLeaderboardCategoryCumulativePoints];

if (!self.gameCenterFeaturesEnabled || !self.achievements){

    return;
}

if(gkScore.rank == 1) {
   ... do my stuff
}
```

Is it possible to get the rank of the player in the weekly leaderboard of iOS GameKit?

some kinde of:

```
if(gkScore.weeklyRank == 1) {
       ... do my stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to test this but you might be able to get what you through using GKLeaderboard...

After you load the leaderboard:

```
yourLeaderBoard.timeScope = GKLeaderboardTimeScopeWeek;
yourLeaderBoard leadScoresWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *scores, NSError *error){

}];
GKScore* gkScore = yourLeaderBoard.localPlayerScore;

(gkScore.rank == 1){
    //Do what you want to do
}
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKLeaderboard_Ref/Reference/Reference.html